# Python search file for earliest date

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to design a function which basically takes a file variable as a parameter and returns a list containing the data of the customer with the earliest account date in the file.

Assuming this is the contents of the file(txt file):

```
12345,Tom,Black,300.00,1998-01-30
23456,Alice,Smith,1200.50,1998-02-20
14567,Jane,White,900.00,1998-07-01
43564,Weilin,Zhao,450.25,1998-01-03
45432,Bina,Mehta,278.95,1998-03-21
```

The code I have is:

```
l = open(r'C:\Users\John\Downloads\customers.txt','r', encoding="utf-8")

contents= l.readlines()

def get_earliest_customer(contents):

    with open(r'C:\Users\John\Downloads\customers.txt','r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        print(min(f, key=(lambda l: string(l.strip().split(",")[4]))))

l.close()

get_earliest_customer(contents)
```

which of courses gives me the erorr:

```
  print(min(f, key=(lambda l: string(l.strip().split(",")[4]))))
  File "C:\Users\John\Home\HPcomputers\src\4.py", line 10, in <lambda>
    print(min(f, key=(lambda l: str(l.strip().split(",")[4]))))
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

Suggestions/comments are appreciated to tackling this issue, I have specified the point that I Want to search for is [4] because the dates on each line is located there.

Comment: What did you intend to accomplish with the call to `string()`? The result of `split()` is already a list of strings.

Comment: There is no `string` in python. `str` is what you want.

Comment: @justanothercoder good headsup

Comment: well i got it working it was just the conversion from string to str lol

Answer (score 1):

```
l = open(r'C:\Users\John\Downloads\customers.txt','r', encoding="utf-8")

contents= l.readlines()

def get_earliest_customer(contents):

    with open(r'C:\Users\John\Downloads\customers.txt','r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        print(min(f, key=(lambda l: str(l.strip().split(",")[4]))))

l.close()

get_earliest_customer(contents)
```

gives output:

```
43564,Weilin,Zhao,450.25,1998-01-03
```

which is what I wanted, thus the change from string to str ,although minor change provided the output I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
file1 = open('data.txt', 'r')

print min([line for line in file1.read().splitlines()], key=lambda x: x.rsplit(',', 1)[1])
```

Output:

```
43564,Weilin,Zhao,450.25,1998-01-03
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is to convert the date string into a date object, and then do the comparison.

I also don't know why you are reading the file twice, and you don't make use of the `contents` variable even though you pass it to your function.

```
import datetime
import csv

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'

def get_earliest_customer(filename):
     contents = []
     with open(filename) as f:
         reader = csv.reader(contents, delimiter=',')
         for row in reader:
             contents = row[:-1]+[datetime.datetime.strptime(row[-1], fmt)]

     return min(contents, key=lambda x: x[-1])

print(get_earliest_customer(r'C:\Users\John\Downloads\customers.txt'))
```